# Saving file to disk while I getting for TIdTCPServer / TIDTCPClient

Tags: delphi

I want to go receiving a file via TIdTCPClient and receiving data that will be saved on disk, such as Skype. In Skype you send a file, the other person accepts and select somewhere to save the file begins to be transferred and the data that have been received will now be saved to disk, so the file is not in RAM. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What have you tried ? Have you tried to search the web for how to do it ?  I could find fair amount of results.

Comment: I can not find, friend. I'm from Brazil, I'm trying to find on other sites. Would you assist me?

Comment: Do you know how to write to a file? Do you know how to receive data over TCP? Why does it matter that you are from Brazil?

Comment: Why am I unable to find anything in Portuguese, so I'm trying something in English. I know send and receive file via TIdTCPServer / Client, but I send a TStream then need to load the entire file into RAM and then send. The server will TStream getting in, staying in RAM. I want a similar transfer files with Skype.

Comment: Do you know Stack Overflow is also available in [portuguese](https://www.google.be/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpt.stackoverflow.com%2F&ei=2Ee6U_vmH4zI0wX3t4HoAw&usg=AFQjCNHmVnFzxUMfJy-iGzYX1Ad78_Qqsg&sig2=bup34juyQq4Mcrjb2wZsdQ&bvm=bv.70138588,d.d2k)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little hard to work out precisely what the question is. But I think the issue is that you don't want to download the entire file to memory, and then write to disk.

I suspect that you are currently using `TMemoryStream` to receive the data. Doing so compels you to receive the entire file to memory. Avoid that quite simply by using `TFileStream` instead. Put the data to a file rather than memory.

Comment: Thank you! Really the TFileStream saved me.

Comment: Good. The question was closed you will see. The information that allowed me to answer was only supplied in a comment. You should really edit the question to include that information.